# Do I have to move my Dropbox folder to work with JupyterLab?

Tags: dropbox, jupyter-lab

The **File** menu in **JupyterLab** has few options for saving and opening files. The menu items do let one browse the file system and search for a directory. For example, the **File->Open from Path...** menu item only allows entering a file on a path relative to **/jlab/root**. Questions:

1. What is the location of **/jlab/root**. Is there a command that shows it?
2. I like to keep files with code in a subfolder of my **Dropbox** folder. What do I do if my **Dropbox** folder is not a subfolder of **/jlab/root**?